# Error using MPI_WTIME with MPI_TESTANY in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am writing an asynchronous load balancer for a Fortran mpi program. I use MPI_TESTANY to check the completeness of an MPI_IRECV call, and MPI_WTIME to measure execution times. 
You can find the complete code at https://github.com/hachat/mpi-pi-calc/blob/experiment/source/load_balancer.f

Lines 207 to 217 are given below, where I got this strange problem.

```
           ...
    ELSE IF(PENDING_RECVS .GT. 0) THEN
    PRINT *,'8ST:', START_TIME(1),' TASK:',TASK
    CALL MPI_TESTANY(NUMTASKS-1,REQUEST_RECV_RES,
 &          TASK,RECV_TEST_FLAG,STATUS_RECV_RES,IERR)

        IF (IERR .NE. MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
          PRINT *,'ERROR IN WAIT FOR RECV RESPONSE. TERMINATING.'
          CALL MPI_ABORT(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, IERR)
        END IF
        PRINT *,'9ST:', START_TIME(1),' TASK:',TASK
           ...
```

Output for the above code is as follows: (for two processes)

...

6ST:   1388151838.3635089
7ST:   1388151838.3635089
1ST:   1388151838.3635089
**8ST:   1388151838.3635089       TASK:           1

9ST:   6.2921131024483548E-316  TASK:           1**
10ST:   6.2921131024483548E-316
11ST:   6.2921131024483548E-316
...

Between the 8ST print and 9ST print the START_TIME(1) variable has been changed!. I tried changing the name and places of START_TIME variables suspecting a buffer overflow, yet had no change with this result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `IMPLICIT NONE` in order to force the compiler to check that all variables have been explicitly declared.

`STATUS_RECV_RES` is not declared explicitly and therefore the compiler creates an implicit `REAL` variable. Since `REAL` is not long enough to hold the whole integer MPI status array, part of the stack gets overwritten when `MPI_TESTANY` finds a completed request. It just happens that your compiler places `START_TIME` array close to `STATUS_RECV_RES` and the first elements of the former become victims by being overwritten.

Also most compilers do not place stack variables (or any variables at all) in the same order as they are declared. This is usually done for both performance reasons and alignment requirements.

Comment: That really worked. Lesson learned the hard way on that forgetting `IMPLICIT NONE`, which is a bad mistake. Thanks very much for the explanatory answer.